# R: handling and plotting grouped data

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a follow up question on this one: [R: plot multiple lines in one graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150183/r-plot-multiple-lines-in-one-graph)

In there I used part of my data to graph 1 graph with multiple lines. Now I want to graph multiple graphs in one grid, since I have grouped data. 
Right now I'm doing this with creating dataframes for each group of data and then creating a graph for each dataframe and combine those using `gridd.arrange()` 
However, I'm wondering if I could handle the grouped data as 1 dataset instead of creating all those separate tables?

The data I have is structured like this:

```
          Category1    Category2    Category3
Company   2011   2013  2011   2013  2011   2013
Company1  300    350   290    300   295    290
Company2  320    430   305    301   300    400
Company3  310    420   400    305   400    410
```

So is there any way to proces this at once and plot the 3 graphs (for each Category) with lines for each Company for the Year (2011 and 2013)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should definitely learn how to structure your data and how to [make a reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It's really hard to deal with data in such an unstructured format. Not only for you, but also for us.

```
mdf <- read.table( text="Company   2011   2013  2011   2013  2011   2013
Company1  300    350   290    300   295    290
Company2  320    430   305    301   300    400
Company3  310    420   400    305   400    410", header = TRUE, check.names=FALSE )

library("reshape2")
cat1 <- melt(mdf[c(1,2,3)], id.vars="Company", value.name="value", variable.name="Year")
cat1$Category <- "Category1"
cat2 <- melt(mdf[c(1,4,5)], id.vars="Company", value.name="value", variable.name="Year")
cat2$Category <- "Category2"
cat3 <- melt(mdf[c(1,6,7)], id.vars="Company", value.name="value", variable.name="Year")
cat3$Category <- "Category3"
mdf <- rbind(cat1, cat2, cat3)

head(mdf)
   Company Year value  Category
1 Company1 2011   300 Category1
2 Company2 2011   320 Category1
3 Company3 2011   310 Category1
4 Company1 2013   350 Category1
5 Company2 2013   430 Category1
6 Company3 2013   420 Category1
```

This can be automated of course, if the number of categories is very large:

```
library( "plyr" )
mdf <- adply( c(1:3), 1, function( cat ){
  tmp <- melt(mdf[ c(1, cat*2, cat*2+1) ], id.vars="Company", value.name="value", variable.name="Year")
  tmp$Category <- paste0("Category", cat)
  return(tmp)
} )
```

But if you can avoid pushing all this data forth and back from the beginning, you should do so.

### Using facets

`ggplot2` has a builtin support for faceted plots displaying data of the same type, if they can be subset by one (or multiple) variables. See `? facet_wrap` or `? facet_grid`.

```
ggplot(data=mdf, aes(x=Year, y=value, group = Company, colour = Company)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point( size=4, shape=21, fill="white") +
    facet_wrap( "Category" )
```

[image]

### Getting individual plots

Alternatively you can subset your `data.frame` by the according variable and store the individual plots in an list:

```
librayr("plyr")
ll <- dlply( mdf, "Category", function(x){
        ggplot(data=x, aes(x=Year, y=value, group = Company, colour = Company)) +
          geom_line() +
          geom_point( size=4, shape=21, fill="white")
})
ll[["Category1"]]
```

Comment: Thx...your help is just why I needed to getting hands-on into R to get more understanding. Still getting used on how to structure data vs how Im used to do it in excel or MySQL ;)

Comment: @Chrisvdberge Well, usually its a completely different deal having having data structured in Excel or (My)SQL (there might be exceptions). The data you showed is how people would do it in Excel while the data in form as as you want them, to work with it in R is how you'd have them organized in SQL.

Comment: you are correct, that actually helps a lot looking at this data ;) Problem was indeed I have this data in excel format.

Answer (score 0):

At least for ggplot2 you'll want to use the **reshape2** package in order to convert your data to a slightly different format.

Let's imagine that you have a data.frame like this:

```
test <- structure(list(Company = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Company1", 
"Company2", "Company3"), class = "factor"), X2011.1 = c(300L, 
320L, 310L), X2013.1 = c(350L, 430L, 420L), X2011.2 = c(290, 
305, 400), X2013.2 = c(300, 301, 305), X2011.3 = c(295, 300, 
400), X2013.3 = c(290L, 400L, 410L)), .Names = c("Company", "X2011.1", 
"X2013.1", "X2011.2", "X2013.2", "X2011.3", "X2013.3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Ignore the ugliness for now, that looks like:

```
  Company  X2011.1 X2013.1 X2011.2 X2013.2 X2011.3 X2013.3
  Company1     300     350     290     300     295     290
  Company2     320     430     305     301     300     400
  Company3     310     420     400     305     400     410
```

If we use the `melt()` function we can make it look like this:

```
melt(test) -> test.melt

test.melt

Using Company as id variables
    Company variable value
1  Company1  X2011.1   300
2  Company2  X2011.1   320
3  Company3  X2011.1   310
4  Company1  X2013.1   350
5  Company2  X2013.1   430
6  Company3  X2013.1   420
7  Company1  X2011.2   290
8  Company2  X2011.2   305
```

Then use the company or `variable` as a grouping factor for ggplot2. Obviously you'll want to name these more sensibly. :)

e.g. you could do

```
ggplot(melt(test)) + geom_bar(aes(x = Company, y = value, fill = variable), stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

Or something.

Comment: thx, but I found that the variation of the 2011 and 2013 values into 2011.1 and 2011.2 is causing a shift in graphs when I use the facets because the X-axis values are slightly different.