# Plot 5 sets of data on a scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have five sets of data that I need on one plot. I need the x-axis to be lidar and the y-axis to be FPC.

I am using `ggplot2`. So far I have the following code:

```
setwd("C:/r/LIDAR_FPC")

AllLidarvsFPC.df <- data.frame(read.csv("AllLidarvsFPC.csv"))
AllLidarvsFPC = read.csv("AllLidarvsFPC.csv", header=TRUE)

library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(AllLidarvsFPC.df, aes(AllLidarvsFPC.df[,1], AllLidarvsFPC.df[,2])) + 
     geom_point() + 
     scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-30,100), breaks=c(-30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)) + 
     scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-10,120), breaks=c(-10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100))`

p + 
labs(y = "2013 Percentage cover (%) derived from LiDAR") + 
labs(x = "2013 FPC (%) derived from Landsat") + 
stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 5), size = 0.5, col="black")
```

However, this only plots the first set of data: `WildmanFPC`.
I need all the FPC data sets plotted!

[image]

Comment: Hi, you would have to add a reproducible code..otherwise it will be too difficult to reproduce your problem on our machines and solve..read here how to do so.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: also see this line `aes(AllLidarvsFPC.df[,1], AllLidarvsFPC.df[,2])) ` you are plotting x vs y only which is i think WildmanFPC

Comment: see this also how to convert your data to long form and then plot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150183/r-plot-multiple-lines-in-one-graph

Comment: With out reproducible code I'm not sure if this will work. Use `melt` to create a long table were the variable will be your colnames, value will be your values stacked. Then a simple colouring can help `P<- ggplot(AllLidarvsFPC.df, aes(x = LIDAR, y= value, color= variable)) + geom_point()`

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no working data to use, I have made a sample data frame to show you how to apply it to your code. 
In the future it is best to provide reproducible code, that way it speeds up responses.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df <- data.frame(LIDAR=c(1,2,3,4), WildmanFPC=c(3,5,2,6), WestAlligatorFPC=c(5,6,7,12), SouthAlligator=c(12,7,1,0))
df_melt<-melt(df, id.vars = 'LIDAR')

ggplot(df_melt, aes(x=LIDAR, y = value, color= variable))+ geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: How about adding an image so we can see what it looks like?