# How to plot multiple lines quickly in R using plot or ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataframe (see below) that has several lines more than shown labeled via the Fly column (each is unique) and a condition that each line received labeled via the condition column. Each line has four measurements associated with it taken at different times. I want to plot volume on the X as volume and Y as time. and color code by the unique line under Fly. Is there a quick and easy way to do this? Not to sure how to get this to work or started with ggplot2() or even plot(). Some help and guidance would be appreciated.

```
     Fly condition_1 volume_1 volume_2 volume_3 volume_4
1     1    postcont      1.6     18.0      8.1     13.5
2     2    postcont      0.0     12.0     10.1      8.5
3     3    postcont      2.6      3.0     10.1      1.5
4     4    postcont     13.6     13.0     10.1     15.5
```

Here is the code up to plotting

```
data1<-read.table(file=file.choose(),header=T)
head(data1)
postcontexp<-subset(data1, condition_1 == "postcont")
postcontexpVOL<- subset(# to remove unwanted columns)
postcontexpVOL<- na.omit(postcontexpVOL)
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a good place to ask for a custom tutorial on the basics of plotting. If you [look at the R tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info), there are many free resources for getting started with R. You can also search for other questions on Stack Overflow. Such as [R plot multiple lines on one graph](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17150183/903061).

Comment: Your data is not tidy, which makes plotting hard because it's hard to plot time if you don't _have_ a time variable because that information is trapped in your column names. Reshape first, e.g. `library(tidyverse) ; df %>% gather(time, volume, starts_with('volume')) %>% mutate(time = parse_number(time))`

Comment: @ Gregor, I understand several basics in ploting. I just dont want to use abline() some number of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version using `melt` from `reshape2` and `dplyr` to fit adjust the data:

```
n <- 4
df <-
  data.frame(
    Ind = 1:n
    , vol_1 = rnorm(n)
    , vol_2 = rnorm(n)
    , vol_3 = rnorm(n)
    , vol_4 = rnorm(n)
  )


melted <-
  melt(df, id.vars = "Ind") %>%
  mutate(Time = as.numeric(gsub("vol_","",variable)))

ggplot(melted
       , aes(x = Time
             , y = value
             , col = as.factor(Ind))) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]