# plot multiple lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I need to plot hourly data for different days using ggplot, and here is my dataset:

[image]

The data consists of hourly observations, and I want to plot each day's observation into one separate line.

Here is my code

```
xbj1 = bj[c(1:24),c(1,6)]
```

`xbj2 = bj[c(24:47),c(1,6)]`
`xbj3 = bj[c(48:71),c(1,6)]`

```
ggplot()+
geom_line(data = xbj1,aes(x = Date, y= Value), colour="blue") +
geom_line(data = xbj2,aes(x = Date, y= Value), colour = "grey") + 
geom_line(data = xbj3,aes(x = Date, y= Value), colour = "green") +
xlab('Hour') +
ylab('PM2.5')
```

Please advice on this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to include the code.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272. Similarly, do not try to post anything significant in a comment ... as you can see, it is rather difficult to read/use. Please just edit your own question and put it there for everybody to see. (Comments can be ignored or hidden if lots of comments ensue, thereby making your question incomplete without those comments.)

Comment: Have you tried `ggplot(x) + geom_line(aes(Hour, Value, color = Date))`?

Comment: can you be more specific on that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot multiple lines in one graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150183/plot-multiple-lines-in-one-graph)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll make some fake data (I won't try to transcribe yours) first:

```
set.seed(2)
x <- data.frame(
  Date = rep(Sys.Date() + 0:1, each = 24),
  # Year, Month, Day ... are not used here
  Hour = rep(0:23, times = 2),
  Value = sample(1e2, size = 48, replace = TRUE)
)
```

This is a straight-forward `ggplot2` plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(x) +
  geom_line(aes(Hour, Value, color = as.factor(Date))) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Date")
```

[image: sample ggplot]

```
ggplot(x) +
  geom_line(aes(Hour, Value)) +
  facet_grid(Date ~ .)
```

[image: sample ggplot, faceted]

I highly recommend you find good tutorials for `ggplot2`, such as http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/. Others exist, many quite good.

Comment: sorry about it... I didn't know about that. Thank you so much for your help!